# The best way to export openerp data to csv file using python

Tags: python, export-to-excel, odoo, export-to-csv

Which is the best to way to export openerp data to csv/xls file using python so that i can schedule it in openerp( i cant use the client side exporting)?

- using csv python package
- using xlwt python package
- or any other package?

And also how can I dynamically provide the path and name to save this newly created csv file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well their are certain ways  like

- using csv python package

  - In this case you can take advantage of the [export_data](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/4557/openerp/osv/orm.py#L1199) service which will automatically produce csv for you, you can use with Scheduler(cron job ) or even you can write script for it.
- using xlwt python package

  - This will be over head for you read all data then process then produce csv while first opption already yours 90% of your job.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to use `Open ERP` client it self.

you can go for `xlwt` if you really require to write a `python` program to generate it.

Comment: i cant use the client side exporting. I need to schedule this function