# Exporting product csv file with a scheduler in OpenERP v6.1

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to export the products to a csv file using a scheduler?
I tried the csv python package discussed in this link: ( [The best way to export openerp data to csv file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187086/the-best-way-to-export-openerp-data-to-csv-file-using-python) ) but it seems I miss something.

I take advantage of the export_data as stated and I point my scheduler to that method but when I run it, nothing happen so I don't know if it runs or not but the scheduler keeps running.

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. What went wrong when you tried using the csv package? Error messages and code snippets help us understand what is happening.

Comment: I have a module that exports data to csv using scheduler. I cant give you the module as it is done for my company. So please mail to anoop@zbeanztech.com/omalbastin@zbeanztech.com. If you are creating module yourself we the Stack Overflow can help you

Comment: @Mhel: Can you provide your scheduler function code here. I guess you making small mistake only. Steps should be call export_data then open some new csv file using csv writer fill the export_data fuction values in new file,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OpenERP (or Odoo) expert. With my current knowledge of Odoo I would get this started through [ERPpeek](https://github.com/tinyerp/erppeek) along the lines of

```
erppeek [YOUR OPENERP DETAILS]
>>> l = model('product.product').browse([])
>>> import csv
>>> with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for prod in l: a.writerow(prod.read().values())
```

I'd further build it out into a script and then put the script in cron.

There are probably better, more standard Odoo-ish ways though.